# Tasks.db in /var/lib/docker/swarm/worker is filling up ( Taking space). How to clear Tasks.db

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Tasks.db file in /var/lib/docker/swarm/worker is taking more than 40gb space

How do i clear the file content with out stopping the docker services

This is our critical service so docker cannot be down

Only option I found was to stop the docker service, remove the file manually
But with this way, all the containers and images in the worker node will get cleared
is there a better way to clean the tasks.db file

Comment: This belongs on a devops not a dev overflow. Is this a single node swarm and is this happening on all (manager) nodes? Why is it happening - do you have an exceptional number of services, or lots of services that are stuck in fail-restart loops? Does `docker system prune -af` not clear up any space?

Comment: Hi @ChrisBecke docker system prune -af did not cleared any space.  This is happening on all the worker nodes. This is a Prod cluster and all the services are upa nd running

Comment: Never seen this kind of behaviour. I'd be very tempted to pull one of the boltdb onto a dev box and examine which tables are growing and what they contain. Then, probably, post an issue to moby/moby.